# Issue with simple PHP Contactform

Tags: php, html

So I have some issues with my PHP Contactform on a HTML site.

Code below is what I have written in HTML. (that's not te problem)

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" required name="email">
<div class="validation">
    <button class="btn" name="submit">Send request</button>
```

// END HTML code. (BELOW is starts PHP).

```
$email_to = "domain@website.com";
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$email_subject = "DOMAINNAME";
$headers = "From: " . $email . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\n";
$message = 'Name: ' . $name . ', email: ' . $email . ', amount: ' . $amount;

ini_set("sendmail", $email);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 
{$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f" .$email);}

{
    header("Location:https://website.com");
} else {
    echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";
}
```

What do I wrong? I only wanna receive the --> name, amount and mail.
Only when I press submit on my HTML site, it's send me to website.com/sendmail.php (HTTP ERROR 500).

Thank you guys.

Comment: Where is your <form> tag ?. try to execute the codes in your php file only by : if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //your code here }

Comment: You mean this?    <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">

I have that.

Comment: Can you properly indent your PHP code? Then I will read it.
Please answer my comment when done so that I can get a notification. There are also many English mistakes but I can deal with that!
Thanks.

Comment: Also, what is the name of your PHP file, is it `sendmail.php`? And what kind of HTTP error are you getting (404, 500, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks, @Rolf. I get the HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: And yes, it's named as sendmail.php. It have the max rights 664.
And the html site 775 rights

Comment: Fixed it. I removed the last row at:  else {
    echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";


So that is causing the error. Now I need to find out where to place the error on my html site. But ok. Thanks all